# Power Supply for VFD Display

Tags: power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, display, vacuum-fluorescent

I recently ordered a GP1294AI VFD display from Aliexpress. Unfortunately it did not contain the necessary power supply to power the display, but the [datasheet](https://cdn.hackaday.io/files/1916648200152576/EPC-INBN0BV1294UD_SPEC.pdf) did include the necessary schematics for a power supply.

However, the components used in the schematic are not available from European retailers. This is why I recreated the schematic using different components. I made a few adjustments and wanted to make sure I made no mistakes before starting on the PCB layout as my power electronics knowledge is limited.

- I will use a 12V supply, so I removed the USB input connector
- I will not use the aux inputs or light sensor so these were removed
- The DCDC boost converters creating 75V and 50V were designed using the online WEBENCH tool from Texas Instruments
- The circuit from the datasheet contains a seperate SMPS for generating 3V3 from 5V. I removed this one as 3V3 is already created by a linear regulator. A high-side switch enabled/disables the filament driver instead.

[image: Adjusted VFD Display Power Supply]
[image: Datasheet VFD Display Power Supply]

All feedback appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Few things I noticed:

- The diodes on bottom-right (VFD section) should connect to each 200R to the left, instead of having all paralleled across CLK pin.
- The connection of the PMOS that is supposed to be used to switch the `V_FILAMENT` is wrong. It's upside down so the body diode will always be in forward bias which means `V_FILAMENT` will always be present regardless of `FILAMENT_EN` signal status. Plus, if the `FILAMENT_EN` signal is a 3.3V logic signal then the Q3 can be omitted:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6c67G.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

> The circuit from the datasheet contains a seperate SMPS for generating 3V3 from 5V. I removed this one as 3V3 is already created by a linear regulator.

- It's not that simple. There must be a reason why they used a separate regulator for `V_FILAMENT`. For example, the current consumption could be higher than the current that the linear regulator can handle. I can see they used BL1117-33CX which is a 3V3/1A regulator, quite similar to the one you have, LM3940. They used the output for VFD as `VFD_VDD` but they didn't use the same voltage for `V_FILAMENT`. Instead, they built a [3.3V/2A synchronous buck](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2109171430_XI-AN-Aerosemi-Tech-MT1470_C181781.pdf) for `V_FILAMENT`. So you should consider a separate regulator with similar specs anyways.

I'll update the post as I find some more things.